# Armature Deform With Automatic Weights Problem

Tags: rigging, armature, parent

I'm having this problem for a while now. I don't know if this was answered before but I can't seem to find any solution for this online. I'm trying to connect a helmet to my armature. Every other part on the armor seems to connect without any problem but this helmet. I've connected everything with parent armature deform w/ auto weights and like I said every other part connects & moves perfectly. I tried to delete vertex groups, scaling up the helmet then parenting, and then scaling down nothing works. I hope you can give me some advice on this, I'm relatively new to rigging and can't figure this out. Thank you.[image: When armature is rotated] [image: When armature stays still]

Comment: Hello and welcome. You probably will need to share your blend file or try to isolate the problem by providing a simple setup with the same problem. https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Automatic Weights does not work well if there are too many bones close together. I guess you don´t want the helmet deformed by tongue or toe. Try the following steps: 1 Select helmet in Objectmode > delete all vertexgroups (down arrow menu right sided). 2 Now select armature with CTRL (helmet selected, armature active) > Editmode > select single head or neck bone > Objectmode > RMB > Parent > Bone. Now the whole helmet is attached to one bone.

Comment: @relaxed THANK YOU so much. I tried your method and it worked. You're a lifesaver.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Thank you 